# Reducing PowerShell memory usage per shell

Tags: shell, powershell, windows-server-2008, sql-server-agent

I have some problems with Windows Powershell 4. I need to execute hundreds of very small (Azure) PowerShell scripts. The problem is that each shell uses 50-70 MB when I look in the Task Manager.

So i tried to use WSman and reduce `MaxMemoryPerShellMB`, for all plugins and all they say on this post :

> http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory.aspx

After that, I restarted the Winrm service and executed PowerShell and it still consumes 50MB. It's the same for my Powershell scripts executed by SQL Server Agent.

Am I missing something? I'm considering rewriting my script with Nodejs and Azure CLI, but I wanted to know why `MaxMemoryPerShellMB` is not working.

I'm on Windows Server 2008 R2 by the way.

Comment: Run all you scripts in one shell using `Start-Job`

Comment: Have you considered using runspaces rather than a full shell session for each script?

Comment: Mmh, not really, I'm new to PowerShell. The context is that each script is triggered by SQL Server Agent and that I need the response to mark the job as Failure or Success.